# Can I make a controller respond to 2 routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have to integrate an old flash gallery into my website. Unfortunately, the swf file has it's xml hardcoded to `/gallery.xml`, and my controller is generating it's xml file at `/attachments.xml`. Can I make the `attachments` resource respond to `/gallery.xml`, and still keep the normal attachment routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a non-resourceful regular route for that

```
resources :attachments # I guess this is what you already have

get "/gallery(.:format)" => "attachments#index"
```

there is no reason it shouldn't work along the resourceful route.